# Tomcat security without a Web Server

Tags: security, web-server, tomcat

Can anyone tell me, from his experience, if is a good approach leaving Tomcat alone (in PRD) and not "hidden" behind a real web server as Apache or IIS?

The application I am deplying on Tomcat is an e-commerce app with a SSL certificate for security modules (payments). So I want to point on security.

Thanks in advance for any light on this matter.

Comment: Yes, it's fine.